# Are python condition variables busy waiting?

Tags: python, concurrency

I have a multithreaded program where the main thread will put events on a queue at arbitrary points in time, and I only want a background thread to be running if the queue is not empty. I.e., I do not want my thread to busy wait, I want it to be put to sleep and only woken up when it is notified. I have a condition variable in my class called `queueNotEmpty` that the main thread calls `notify()` on whenever something is added to the queue. Does the following meet my needs, or is this still busy waiting inside the `wait()` call?

```
while(not self.terminate):
    try:
        eventName, info = self.eventQueue.get(block=False)
        event = trigger(eventName, info)
    except Queue.Empty:
        self.queueNotEmpty.acquire()
        self.queueNotEmpty.wait()
        self.queueNotEmpty.release()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to kick down an open door. This basically does same thing as you code above without extra complication in the code and and without loops cycles wasted due potential race condition.

```
while(not self.terminate):
    eventName, info = self.eventQueue.get()
    event = trigger(eventName, info)
```

Queue blocking is *not* active waiting.

Update: internal workings of `Queue` are described for example in blog post ["Python threads synchronization: Locks, RLocks, Semaphores, Conditions, Events and Queues"](http://www.laurentluce.com/posts/python-threads-synchronization-locks-rlocks-semaphores-conditions-events-and-queues/). According to that source, it's implemented like this:

```
def get(self, block=True, timeout=None):
    ...
    self.not_empty.acquire()
    try:
        ...
        elif timeout is None:
            while not self._qsize():
                self.not_empty.wait()
        item = self._get()
        self.not_full.notify()
        return item
    finally:
        self.not_empty.release()
```

Comment: Are you certain? In reading the documentation of the blocking queue get(), it sounded like it was using a spinlock

Comment: as far as I know, it uses underlying OS implementation of threading conditions

Comment: @zjm555 What about the documentation sounds like that? If you really wanted to know, you should look at the implementation (and be aware of the caveats of that). But unless documented otherwise, it's a reasonable null hypothesis that the implementation is as efficient as it can reasonably be.

Comment: @delnan Fair point. I am satisfied by the concensus here for now, in the interest of time :) Thanks all

Comment: Yes, that's the whole point of Queues - to avoid wasting CPU continually checking. If the documentation isn't clear on that then it's a documentation bug.

Answer (score 1):

If you call `.get()` on a `Queue.Queue` object with `block=True` (the default) then your thread will automatically be suspended until there is something for it to read from the queue. If several threads are all trying to read the queue then there are no guarantees about which one will manage to read it.

The main purpose of `Queue.Queue` is to enable reliable inter-thread communications, so blocking and synchronization are baked right in.